# Python temp arrays sort

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

Why output like this?

```
    years = [1998,2000,1998,1987]
    
    x = years
    x.sort()
    
    print(x)
    print(years) #why not [1998,2000,1998,1987]
```

Output:

```
[1987, 1998, 1998, 2000]
[1987, 1998, 1998, 2000]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent

Comment: The line `x = years` sets `x` to point on `years` list, therefore from that point on they point the same object (until you change it).

So, when you sort, you sort the same object and when you print those variables the result is the same sorted array.

Comment: you can print(id(x)),print(id(years)),to see there address

Comment: You could also use x = sorted(years) as this created a new sorted list leaving the original

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you assign it to another variable the reference to that list is assign to another variable, so both of them assigning to same list, then when you change the list, both of them will be change.
you can use `copy` to prevent this to happen, like this:

```
from copy import copy

x = copy(years)
```

or

```
x = years[:]
```

Comment: Since the op wants to sort the list immediately after the copy, I think it's worth mentioning `x = sorted(years)` as another option.

Comment: @Stef Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

you copy the location
use:

```
x=years[:]
```

that will work.